# Convertir string a number

Tags: javascript, string, regex

Tengo que hacer uso de la siguiente API (https://api.itbook.store/1.0/new) y estoy con el problema de que el precio de los libros esta en forma de string y no estoy encontrando forma de pasarlo a number. estoy haciendo uso de Number(), pero no obtengo resultado. mi problema es que al multiplicarlo en el carrito con la cantidad de libros y el precio, me da como error NaN.

```
            <p className="lead fw-bold">
              {book.price} X {book.qty} = {book.price * book.qty}
            </p>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: 1) book.price no es un número por eso te arroja NaN, tiene un signo $ como prefijo. 2) No tiene sentido transformarlo a número si no vas a realizar alguna operación con él. En tu código básicamente lo que estás haciendo es transformar un string a número y luego volver a transformarlo en string (porque todo lo que se imprime en HTML es string)

Comment: Yo lo necesito como numero para poder realizar la operacion en el carrito de compras para multiplicar la cantidad de libros por el precio y luego calcular el total

Comment: comparte como se ve book.price y de que tipo es, tambien como quieres que sea su formato de salida como tipo numerico

Comment: Lo necesito que se muestre en entero ya intente con el parseInt, ahi actualice la pregunta. use el console.log(typeof book.price) y en consola me lo imprime como string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que no puedes convertir a number un string con un simbolo **$**, al no poder hacer la conversión, cuando se intenta hacer la multiplicación de un number x un string devuelve NAN, incluso si quitaras el simbolo de pesos la operación se haría ya que JavaScript haría la conversión necesaria, pero puedes asegurarte de que los valores sean del tipo Number con dicho método.

Se podría resolver de diversas maneras, una podría ser usando una expresión regular que remueva lo que no es necesario del string y wrappearlo en un Number()

**Ejemplo 1:**

```
Number(book.price.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));
```

Otra opción podría ser quitar el símbolo de $ con algún metodo ejemplo slice y finalmente convertir a Number.

**Ejemplo 2:**

```
const tempPrice = book.price.slice(1) //Aquí se quita el símbolo de pesos. (esto se puede hacer de muchas maneras, replace, substring, slice, etc)
```

Finalmente bastaría con convertir tempPrice a Number.
**Ejemplo:**

```
const convertedPrice = Number(tempPrice)
```

---

**En este caso puntual** y con el **formato** del número ingresado en book.price (**$xx.yy**) podrías hacer algo como:

```
Number(book.price.slice(1))
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!

Comment: Un placer, quedo a las órdenes.